# How to create a n*10 matrix?

Tags: python

I have to create n*10 matrix in python. I used with

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(m,10))
```

I am getting error 'm' is not defined.please,help me through it.

Comment: Do you define `m` anywhere? What is `m`?For example this would work fine: `m = 5; a = np.zeros(shape=(m,10))`

Comment: Initialise `m` before using.

Comment: 10 columns...but how many rows? you didn't define it

Comment: i have to create nrows with 10 column matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
m=10
ls = []
for x in range(0,m):
    ls.append([y for y in range(x+1,x+11)])
a = np.array(ls)
print(a)
```

I think this solution will work according to your expectation

Comment: But i have to create a matrix with nrows with 10 columns.

Comment: yes you can create nrows where n = m and value of m can be any number you assign to m

Comment: Actually I have to create a matrix based one column values presented in the dataframe. For first row i have to get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.next row should be 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 like that i have to create a matrix.Each time i have to increment by 1.How to do that?

Comment: Provide me sample input and output

Comment: How put sample input and output?

Comment: @Navya try to run my solution given above hopefully it will work as your expectation

Comment: I run above code.But expected output should be based on column values. We have to give number of columns i.e,10 and rows=length(colname).

Comment: What exactly you want can you explain it will details

Comment: col1<-df$col

p=10

df=data.frame(matrix(ncol = p))

for(i in 1:length(df$col)){
  
  
  df[i,]<-col1[i:(p+(i-1))]
  
}

Comment: The above code written in R. Is that clear to you @vashdev? I don't know how to put code in stack over flow.

Comment: Help me through the how to write above code in python.

Comment: I don't know R language

Comment: Thank you for responding @Vashdev